# Set hue using a range of values in Seaborn stripplot

Tags: colors, range, seaborn

I am trying to set hue based on a range of values rather than unique values in seaborn stripplot. For example, different colors for different value ranges (1940-1950, 1950-1960 etc.).

```
sns.stripplot('Condition', 'IM', data=dd3, jitter=0.3, hue= dd3['Year Built'])
```

[Output Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbzRH.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to bin the data. Use [.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) in the below manner. The years are binned into 5 groups. You can arrange your own `step` in [.arrange()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to adjust your ranges.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(0,100,size=100)
y = np.random.randint(0,100, size=100)
year = np.random.randint(1918, 2019, size=100)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':x,
    'y':y,
    'year':year
})

df['year_bin'] = pd.cut(df['year'], np.arange(min(year), max(year), step=20))
sns.lmplot('x','y', data=df, hue='year_bin')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]